# How can I make a span increases in width from the opposite side it.

Tags: html, css

I have a *span* tag that has a name inside of it. When I change the name, I want the end of the name to stay in the same place while the beginning of the name moves. So lets say I have a span with the name Eric in it.

```
<span>Eric</span>

------Eric------
```

And when I change the name to Johnathan, The position of where the *C* was is now where the *N* is located and the rest of the name extends backwards.

```
<span>Johnathan</span>

-Johnathan------
```

It usually adds on to the other side like so:

```
<span>Eric</span>

------Eric------


<span>Johnathan</span> 

------Johnathan-
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If your span has width greater than the text, you could simply do `text-align: right`, otherwise you could `float: right` the span so the width increases from the left. (this will work but will depend on your rest of the layout).

Comment: @JoshC thanks for the edit, answered through cellphone so couldn't format properly. :)

Answer (score 0):

`span` is an `inline` element, so you can't change it's `width`.

you can use `div` or change the `display` style of the `span` to 'inline-block'

```
<span style="display:inline-block; width:100px; text-align:right;">Eric</span>
```